# Script for sending commands via ssh and not wait till and leave the terminal

Tags: shell-script, ssh, terminal, remote

I have sevaral computers, combined into network with Ethernet switch.
All are running Fedora server and have connection to Internet.

What I need is a script, which:

- Connects to all nodes from list
- Sends commands or pack of commands (like update all or install some packages)
- Closes the connection, but keeps commands running on target machines

Currently, script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
targets_username='username'
targets_password='password'
targets_IPs=( 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.102 )

SCRIPT1='dnf update -y'
SCRIPT2='dnf update -y && poweroff'

for IP in ${targets_IPs[@]}; do
        export SSHPASS=$targets_password
        script="nohup sh -c \"( ( $SCRIPT1 & > /dev/null) &)\""
        echo $IP
        echo $script
        sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $targets_username@$IP $script
done
```

The  problems are:

- as soon as connection is closed, commands stop running
- if command contains extra command like `reboot` or `poweroff` it is forwarded to main computer, from which this script started.

How to fix that?

I found posts [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9748364) about possible solutions, but they didn't work.

Comment: Do things change if you pass `-n -T` to `ssh` ?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but you could use https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/execution/remote_execution.html
for this sort of thing.

Comment: Consider using "expect".  See https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/

Comment: Double-quote your variables when you use them and a lot of your issues will vanish.

Comment: @StephenHarris No. Nochanges either with `-n -T` of just `-n` or just `-T`

Comment: @roaima Double-quoting of `$script` variable didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of invocations are always tricky, because you have to make sure that things are evaluated in the correct place. Ie. add the correct amount of backslashes.

If you do

```
script="sh -c \"nohup sh -c '$SCRIPT1' > /dev/null 2>&1 & \""
sshpass -e ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $targets_username $IP "$script"
```

it should do what you want (notice the `-n` to keep stdin closed). You can verify that the ssh connection indeed closes by adding `time` before the sshpass command, or by running `netstat` in `$SCRIPT1` and checking for open connections.

You need to make sure that stdin, stdout, and stderr are all closed, otherwise `ssh` will wait until they do, even if the process has been backgrounded.

If the above does not work, there may be an additional evaluation of the command line arguments by `sshpass`. Also, the use of single quotes around `$SCRIPT1` delays expansion of e.g. shell variables inside `$SCRIPT1` until the remote side.

Now, even though you can accomplish the task with this approach, I would recommend you use a tool dedicated for this kind of automation, e.g. Ansible (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html). With the background approach, you'll have to check manually (or with another developed tool) whether the command was successful or not, or if it is done executing.

Comment: With this implementation it provides error: `Unknown cipher type '"nohup'`

Comment: I updated the answer. There were two errors: the `-l` had an @ which swallowed the hostname. This is why ssh was still parsing parameters like `-c` for the cipher. And put double quotes on `$script` for safety.